# DateTimeOffset support for EF Core within In-Memory SqlLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core, datetimeoffset

I am using Entity Framework Core to make use of an in-memory SQLite database for the purpose of unit testing.

I create the in-memory context as follows:

```
var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:");
await connection.OpenAsync();

var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
builder.UseSqlite(connection);

var dbContext = new AppDbContext(builder.Options);
```

When I have a table that has date/time-related information I store the data as a DateTimeOffset.  The problem is that SQLite does not support date/time datatypes.  I've seen that there are ways to configure EF to treat that data as ticks (or some other datatype like a string) but I have not been able to figure it out in the context of EF Core.

Any solution that doesn't require me to alter the database design would be fantastic.  Of course, ease of implementation would be preferable as well but beggars can't be choosers.  Thank you!

Comment: Translation mentioned here can help you.
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4108#issuecomment-279837564

Comment: SQLite does not support DateTimeOffset. Whichever way you have decided to store data on server (May be Ticks), you could use a value convertor to convert data to & fro from server in EF Core 2.1